# How can I make a function to make a child of an object in the library based on the variables supplied?

Tags: actionscript-3, function

I'm trying to do a little project for my class and though I know how to do it the long way I'd prefer to do it in a more intuitive way so that I can avoid having to copy and paste a load of essentially the same code. The idea is to have a function which will create an instance of a class object with it's own unique name, set it's position/size/etc, and then add that child to the stage. Looking at this (what I have now) might help out a little bit.

```
//Set up variables for all deco pieces
var decoGreen:GreenBall;
var decoRed:RedBall;
var decoStar:Star;
var decoFlower:Flower1;
var decoYellow:YellowBall;
var decoBlue:BlueBall;

//Functions to allow easier object placement
function makeDeco(posX:Number, posY:Number, decoName:String, rootClass:Object):void
{
    decoName = new (rootClass)();
    decoName.x = posX;
    decoName.y = posY;
    addChild((decoName));

}
makeDeco(90,320,"greenBall",GreenBall)
```

Now obviously this code doesn't work and it's pretty rough right now but I think it's sufficient to understand what I'm trying to accomplish here. Thanks for any and all who attempt to decipher my mess! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close from what I can tell and if I understand your question, it would simply be using the `getDefinitionByName` class

```
function makeDeco(posX:Number, posY:Number, decoName:String):void
{
    var DecoClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(decoName) as Class;
    var deco:DisplayObject = new DecoClass();
    deco.x = posX;
    deco.y = posY;
    addChild((deco));
}
makeDeco(90,320,"greenBall")
```

You don't need to define the variables initially like you did, granted they've all set to "Export as actionscript" in the library. For example calling a string of "greenBall" would mean you have a movie clip in the library with a class name of `greenBall`

Comment: This makes sense, however I still can't get it to run without throwing me errors. What's this error trying to tell me? (I ran the code above). `ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable decoGreen is not defined.
 at global/flash.utils::getDefinitionByName()
 at ChristmasDecorationFSt_fla::MainTimeline/makeDeco()
 at ChristmasDecorationFSt_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
`

Comment: you have a movie clip called "decoGreen" in the library?

Comment: and not the actual name, but the AS linkage rather needs to be called `decoGreen`

Comment: Ohhhhhh. The whole time I thought I could have the decoName as anything I wanted, but rather it's used to call the particular object from the library. Works perfect, thanks a whole bunch! :D